# I am trying to get cookies from the server. But set cookie doesn't work

Tags: express

Express part

```
await res
            .status(response.statusCode)
            .cookie("token", response.data.token, {
              path: "/",
              maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
              httpOnly: false,
              sameSite: "none",
            })
            .json(response);
```

client part

```
const config = { headers: { withCredentials: true } };

export const login = (datas) => API.post("/api/auth/login", datas, config);
```

browser get

```
  Set-cookie: token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiI; Max-Age=604800; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 03 Nov 2021 15:39:35 GMT; SameSite=None
```

But in application cookies is empty

Comment: Is the express server running on a different hostname than the hostname that serves the client?

Comment: One hostname is used for server and client

Comment: do you use cookie-parser ?

Comment: yes, I using cookie-parser. Also I add  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);. But that dont help

Comment: Cookie is empty in application . But when the client makes a get request, the server receives a cookie. Also document.cookie or document.cookies is empty